# Amazon Lex in react-native app should Query to SQL database and answer user question

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-lambda

I have successfully integrated Lex in react-native app. following below steps

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/interactions

below is my React-native Lex App:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, SafeAreaView, Alert, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import { ChatBot } from 'aws-amplify-react-native';
import voiceLibs from 'aws-amplify-react-native/dist/Interactions/ReactNativeModules'

import awsconfig from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
  },
});

export default class App extends Component {

    state = {
        botName: 'SampleBotApp',
        welcomeMessage: 'Welcome, what would you like to do today?',
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleComplete = this.handleComplete.bind(this);
    }

    handleComplete(err, confirmation) {
        if (err) {
        Alert.alert('Error', 'Bot conversation failed', [{ text: 'OK' }]);
        return;
        }

        Alert.alert('Done', JSON.stringify(confirmation, null, 2), [{ text: 'OK' }]);

        this.setState({
        botName: 'SampleBotApp',
        });

        return 'Thank you! what would you like to do next?';
    }

    render() {
        const { botName, showChatBot, welcomeMessage } = this.state;

        return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <ChatBot
            botName={botName}
            welcomeMessage={welcomeMessage}
            onComplete={this.handleComplete}
            clearOnComplete={false}
            styles={StyleSheet.create({
                itemMe: {
                color: 'red'
                }
            })}
          voiceEnabled={true}
          voiceLibs={voiceLibs}
          conversationModeOn={true}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }

}
```

> my requirement is to get input from user like "How many students opted
>   for English subject?" connect to SQL database query the result and
>   response to be given back to user saying "There are 20 students opted
>   for English subject.".

i really don't know how i can connect to SQL database and query result to direct to Lex so that Lex will give proper response.

i have POST api's will return me JSON object, i had connected in C# earliier for .Net project. but in react native (javascript) how i can read response from Amazon Lex and query to database and get back the result and Lex will respond to user..

Thanks in advance....

Comment: if any one has worked can direct me to sample or anything where i can start...i am researching on same....